# Why Sql browser local connection works when turned off

Tags: sql

I recently get to interesting issue with Sql server browser. I have Win 2008 R2 datacenter server running multiple instances of Sql server and Sql browser. The instances are running under dynamic port numbers.

I am using these instances as bases for my employer's application and that application is connecting to these instances with ADO using connection string formatted "SERVER NAME\INSTANCE NAME".

When Sql server browser is not running on server machine, any network connections from that application are unsuccesfull, but local connections are successfull.

How is application able to connect localy, being a fact, that Sql server browser is not running ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't work with SQL Server all that often anymore but if I'm not mistaken local connections will first use Shared Memory (which is enabled by default) and then use TCP/IP or Named Pipes (if enabled). You can confirm this by disabling Shared Memory, restarting SQL Server and trying your local connection again.

Comment: Shared memory has been disabled prior testing and program was still able to connect to sql server locally with sql browser turned off.